# Solve a first order partial differential equation with the boundary condition $u(x,x+x^2)=\sin(x)$ instead of a initial value.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

The problem I want to solve is the following one:
$$
\begin{cases}
u_x + u_t + u = 1,\\
u(x,x+x^2)=\sin(x).
\end{cases}
$$
I know how to use method of characteristic only if a initial value condition is given in $t=0$: loosely speaking I know how to deal with boundary conditions in the form $u_0(x)=u(x,0)$. What is the solution in the above case? Thanks!

Comment: According to [Mathematica](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83Ysj.png) the solution is $u(x,\, t) = e^{-\sqrt{t - x} - x} \cdot \left(e^{\sqrt{t - x} + x} - \sin\left( \sqrt{t - x} \right) - 1 \right))$. [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=D%5BExp%5B-Sqrt%5Bt-x%5D-x%5D*%28Exp%5BSqrt%5Bt-x%5D%2Bx%5D-1%29%2Ct%5D%2BD%5BExp%5B-Sqrt%5Bt-x%5D-x%5D*%28Exp%5BSqrt%5Bt-x%5D%2Bx%5D-1%29%2Cx%5D%2BExp%5B-Sqrt%5Bt-x%5D-x%5D*%28Exp%5BSqrt%5Bt-x%5D%2Bx%5D-1%29%3D%3D1) confirms this.
Code: DSolve[{D[u[x, t], x] + D[u[x, t], t] + u[x, t] == 1, u[x, x + x^2] == Sin[x]}, u[x, t], {x, t}]

Comment: Thanks! However Mathematica solution wouldn't tell me enough about how to solve problems like this, thus I'm interested in step-by-step solution.

Comment: The basic idea of method of characteristic is along the characteristic, you know the behavior of $u$. To compute the value of $u$ at a $(x,t)$, you first figure out the characteristic passes through that point and then the location where this characteristic intersect the boundary. In this case, the characteristic are straight lines $x - t = const$. so if $(x_0,x_0+x_0^2)$ is the point of interesction, then $x_0 = \sqrt{t - x}$. The remaining treatment isn't that different from the case whether the boundary is along the $x$-axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The characteristic curves satisfy the ODEs
\begin{align}
\dot{x}(s)&=1, \tag{1} \\
\dot{t}(s)&=1, \tag{2} \\
\dot{u}(s)&=1-u. \tag{3}
\end{align}
Solving them, with initial conditions $x(0)=x_0, t(0)=t_0,$ and $u(0)=u_0$, we obtain
\begin{align}
x&=x_0+s, \tag{4} \\
t&=t_0+s, \tag{5} \\
u&=1+(u_0-1)e^{-s}. \tag{6}
\end{align}
The boundary condition $u(x,x+x^2)=\sin(x)$ is equivalent to
\begin{align}
t_0&=x_0+x_0^2, \tag{7} \\
u_0&=\sin(x_0). \tag{8}
\end{align}
Plugging $(7)$ into $(5)$ and solving $(4)$-$(5)$ for $x_0$ and $s$, we obtain
\begin{align}
x_0&=\sqrt{t-x}, \tag{9} \\
s&=x-\sqrt{t-x}. \tag{10}
\end{align}
Finally, plugging $(8)$-$(10)$ into $(6)$, we obtain
$$
u(x,t)=1+e^{-x+\sqrt{t-x}}\left(\sin(\sqrt{t-x})-1\right). \tag{11}
$$